# Facebook Graph API: Get user_location

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to get the location of my facebook friends using the Graph API?

Answer (score 8):

Your friend is considered a *user*, so you go to the [user documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/), get the field name `location` (to be send in the `fields` parameter) AND you check if you need a specific permission:

> Requires `user_location` or
>   `friend_location` permission

HOWEVER there's a typo! to get your friend's location you need the `friends_location` (with ***s***), [reference](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions).

Here's a PHP-SDK example:

```
$facebook->api('/friend_id', 'get', array("fields"=>"name,location"));
```

Here I'm retrieving the `name` and `location` fields (please note that the `id` field will be retrieved automatically).

Comment: Does this work for you? I really can't get it to work. Only name is returned (asking for perms correctly with friendS_location as well).

Comment: @grm: yes it does **BUT** your friend should have set the city to appear! I found that 40% of my friends didn't set it!

Comment: Remember that the location field returns an object. In order to retrieve the location you have to use $profile['location']->name.

Answer (score 2):

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    var location = response.location.name;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way to get all the information you want from friends of a user you can use the FQL method:

```
$this->api->api(array('method'=>'fql.query','query'=>"SELECT uid,name,first_name,middle_name,last_name,pic_square,hometown_location,current_location,profile_url,email,website FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())"));
```

For a list of all the tables with their corresponding column names I refer to: [Facebook FQL Reference](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/)

Answer (score 1):

The FaceBook Documentation has the information you're looking for, including sample code and instructions. It's available at:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas

You may also find the Graph API useful: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api

Comment: as a little hint, typically, you'll want to answer with more than just a link. Including sample code and detailed instructions are great ways to produce high quality answers. I edited your answer just a little bit to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token="get this from fb tool"&fields=location

Answer (score 1):

```
fql?q=SELECT locale,current_location from user where uid in(select uid2 from friend where uid1=me())
```

Requires user_location or friend_location permission

Answer (score 0):

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    document.getElementById("UserLocation").innerHTML = response.location.name; 
});
```

In your HTML code call `UserLocation` Id in any HTML tag. ex.

```
<div id="UserLocation"></div>
```